# Querying database schema with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to write an application which I can point at different databases and look at the database's schema, that is, tables and their column's properties, relationships, constraints, etc. I've been looking into the [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL_.28formerly_called_DLINQ.29) method GetTable(), but this appears to return nothing;

```
public static IEnumerable<MetaTable> GetMetaTables()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var context = new SchemaDataContext(connection))
           return context.Mapping.GetTables().ToList();
}
```

What am I doing wrong!?

Comment: Have you actually created entities in SchemaDataContext?

Comment: Nope! I guess that's the issue here, I need a way of querying all tables regardless of entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>`var model = new AttributeMappingSource().GetModel(typeof({YourDataContext}));
    return model.GetTables().ToList();`</s>

---

**Edit to my original solution:**

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    DataTable table = connection.GetSchema("Tables");

    // displaying data:
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", col.ColumnName, row[col]);
        }
}
```

Comment: If you already have an instance of the data context, the meta model is accessible from the `Mapping` property, so this solution won't work either.

Comment: It worked for me and I've also updated the solution as it didn't really make sense to over-complicate the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have entities `SchemaDataContext`, so there are no mappings at all. But if you don't have entities in `SchemaDataContext` anyway, you really shouldn't use an ORM.

Here is a simpler solution, without Linq to SQL:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetTables()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        foreach (var table in connection.GetSchema("Tables").Rows)
        {
            yield return (string)table[2];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may have to suffice, although I was hoping to map the results to an object so I wouldn't have to access the results in a messy datatable, via indexes!

Comment: Update: this ain't gonna cut the mustard. There seems to be no way of suitably interrogating foreign key constraints with this technique. (You can see what constraints are on what table but that's about as far as it goes).